# curl query to check out a document using CMIS

Tags: curl, alfresco, cmis, atompub

I am trying to checkout a document using the REST-based [CMIS protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services), but I get an error from the server ([Alfresco](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Web_Scripts_Reference#Checkout_Document_.28checkOut.29)).

Am I misusing curl?
Or am I missing something in my request?

```
curl --user admin:admin -F "atomentry=@atomentry.xml" http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/checkedout
```

With atomentry.xml being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/"
xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/">
<cmisra:object>
<cmis:properties>
<cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectId">
<cmis:value>workspace://SpacesStore/3e13d089-39cf-48a4-b0b6-773b602bbcc0</cmis:value>
</cmis:propertyId>
</cmis:properties>
</cmisra:object>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wrong with both curl and the XML... here is what worked:

```
curl -X POST -uadmin:admin "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/cmis/checkedout" -H "Content-Type:application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=UTF-8" -d @atomentry.xml
```

With atomentry.xml being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/" xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/">
<cmisra:object>
<cmis:properties>
<cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectId">
<cmis:value>workspace://SpacesStore/3e13d089-39cf-48a4-b0b6-773b602bbcc0</cmis:value>
</cmis:propertyId>
</cmis:properties>
</cmisra:object>
</entry>
```