# Alfresco Create private working copy

Tags: alfresco, checkout, working-copy, opencmis

I use Alfresco Community4.0.e, chemistry-opencmis-client 0.7.0,primefaces 3.4.1
i want to add "Edit offline" feature to my attachment Files in my web application
to do this I try to use the Web Scripts "checkedout" but I couldn't find the proper way to invoke this Web Scripts
I run this Web Scripts through "CMIS WorkBench" and I tried to read the log
I found that alfresco invoke this Web Scripts like this

`DEBUG ent.bindings.spi.http.DefaultHttpInvoker: POST http://fateh:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/checkedout`

`TRACE ent.bindings.spi.http.DefaultHttpInvoker: POST http://fateh:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/checkedout > Headers: {null=[HTTP/1.1 201 Created], Date=[Tue, 16 Jul 2013 10:38:53 GMT],Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Location=[http://fateh:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/pwc/s/workspace:SpacesStore/..., Content-Type=[application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=UTF-8], Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1],Pragma=[no-cache], Cache-Control=[no-cache]}`

i try to write code to match what i understand from the log but it not working -_-

```
 public String cancelCheckOut(String objID) throws JSONException{
     try{
         HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://"+Constant.getAlfrescoIpConcatPort()+"/alfresco/service/cmis/checkedout");
         //StringEntity requestEntity  =new StringEntity(json);
         //httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);
         httpPost.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
         httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/atom+xml");
         httpPost.setHeader("Location", "http://50.17.228.246:80/alfresco/service/cmis/pwc/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/5b4772c9-8d8d-4fab-a7b9-5fe5d25b45f1");
         httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=UTF-8");
         httpPost.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
         httpPost.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

         System.out.println("Http post "+ httpPost.toString());

         HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
         System.out.println("response "+ response.toString());

         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         if (entity != null) {
                 return "done";
         }
    }catch (Exception ex) {         
        System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    return "failed";    
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found more Easy Way to create Private Working copy Because I not used before curl query

```
Session session = CMISUtils.getSession();
Document doc = (Document) session.getObject(session.createObjectId(attachment.getIdAttachment()));
Document pwc = (Document) session.getObject(doc.checkOut());
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to add add a payload to your POST to specify the document you'd like to checkout, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/"
    xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/">
    <cmisra:object>
    <cmis:properties>
    <cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectId">
    <cmis:value>workspace:/SpacesStore/5b4772c9-8d8d-4fab-a7b9-5fe5d25b45f1</cmis:value>
    </cmis:propertyId>
    </cmis:properties>
    </cmisra:object>
 </entry>
```

[curl query to check out a document using the CMIS protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631510/curl-query-to-check-out-a-document-using-the-cmis-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

Just to explicit on alfrescian's answer, here is what you have to write before client.execute:

```
String data = "what alfrescian wrote";
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(data));
```

Comment: thanks All for you Answers

But I found more Easy Way to create Private Working copy Because i not used before curl query

Session session = CMISUtils.getSession();
Document doc = (Document) session.getObject(session.createObjectId(attachment.getIdAttachment()));
Document pwc = (Document) session.getObject(doc.checkOut());